# Android - HTTP POST and GET login and view html

Tags: java, android, html

I am trying to log in to facebook given a users credentials and receive the html of the webpage using HTTP POST and GET. Here is my code:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.facebook.com/");
    HttpResponse response = null;


    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", USEREMAIL));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", USERPASSWORD));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "Log In"));
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        System.out.println("HERE 3");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
         response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 400);

        // write response to log
        Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        System.out.println("HERE 2");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //ATTEMPT 3
    String htmlsource = "";
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader myreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = myreader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
          string.append(line + "\n");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    htmlsource = string.toString();
    System.out.println(htmlsource);
```

It is supposed to print out all the html of the page AFTER a login, but instead it simply prints out the HTML of the login page. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the HTML output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script>function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){window.requireLazy(['Env'],b);}else{window.Env=window.Env||{};b(window.Env);}}envFlush({"ajaxpipe_token":"AXg9mPow7WZQS-1I","lhsh":"DAQEgAACr"});</script>
      <script>CavalryLogger=false;</script>
      <noscript>
         <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgroups%2F123435454667253%2F&amp;_fb_noscript=1" />
      </noscript>
      <meta name="referrer" content="default" id="meta_referrer" />
      <title id="pageTitle">Log into Facebook | Facebook</title>
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="Facebook" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgroups%2F123435454667253%2F" />
      <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="www" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_LA" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="it_IT" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="id_ID" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="th_TH" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="vi_VN" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="ko_KR" />
      <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/osd.xml" title="Facebook" />
      <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="https://m.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ar" href="https://ar-ar.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="bg" href="https://bg-bg.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="bs" href="https://bs-ba.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ca" href="https://ca-es.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="da" href="https://da-dk.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="el" href="https://el-gr.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://es-la.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-es" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fa" href="https://fa-ir.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fi" href="https://fi-fi.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://fr-fr.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-ca" href="https://fr-ca.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="hi" href="https://hi-in.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="hr" href="https://hr-hr.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="id" href="https://id-id.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="https://it-it.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko" href="https://ko-kr.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="mk" href="https://mk-mk.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ms" href="https://ms-my.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl" href="https://pl-pl.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt" href="https://pt-br.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt-pt" href="https://pt-pt.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ro" href="https://ro-ro.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sl" href="https://sl-si.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sr" href="https://sr-rs.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="https://th-th.facebook.com/login/" />
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="vi" href="https://vi-vn.facebook.com/login/" />
      <meta name="description" content="Log into Facebook to start sharing and connecting with your f
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yZ/r/qaYt59faGzN.css" data-bootloader-hash="MQYLf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yP/r/vlPkWrC9J6K.css" data-bootloader-hash="crKAN" data-permanent="1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y3/r/311YCWGYxkv.css" data-bootloader-hash="Pv1hP" data-permanent="1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yO/r/33VXNjZb2YN.css" data-bootloader-hash="mwDzO" data-permanent="1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yW/r/Fb1_ZpJ4hVD.css" data-bootloader-hash="1Nw/a" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <script src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yB/r/fKHl0IjQ8yw.js" data-bootloader-hash="WUP2n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>require("TimeSlice").guard(function() {(require("ServerJSDefine")).handleDefines([["URLFragmentPreludeConfig",[],{"incorporateQuicklingFragment":true,"hashtagRedirect":true},137],["BootloaderConfig",[],{"maxJsRetries":0,"jsRetries":null,"jsRetryAbortNum":2,"jsRetryAbortTime":5},329],["CSSLoaderConfig",[],{"timeout":5000,"modulePrefix":"BLCSS:"},619],["UserAgentData",[],{"browserArchitecture":"32","browserFullVersion":null,"browserMinorVersion":null,"browserName":"Unknown","browserVersion":null,"deviceName":"Unknown","engineName":"Unknown","engineVersion":null,"platformArchitecture":"32","platformName":"Unknown","platformVersion":null,"platformFullVersion":null},527],["TrackingConfig",[],{"domain":"https:\/\/pixel.facebook.com"},325],["WebSpeedExperiments",[],{"non_blocking_tracker":false,"non_blocking_logger":false},1160],["CurrentCommunityInitialData",[],{},490],["CurrentUserInitialData",[],{"USER_ID":"0","ACCOUNT_ID":"0"},270],["DTSGInitialData",[],{},258],["ISB",[],{},330],["LSD",[],{"token":"AVqyFOZj"},323],["SiteData",[],{"revision":2144174,"tier":"","push_phase":"V3","pkg_cohort":"EXP1:DEFAULT","spdy_enabled":false,"haste_site":"www","vip":"31.13.77.36"},317],["LinkshimHandlerConfig",[],{"supports_meta_referrer":false,"default_meta_referrer_policy":"default","render_verification_rate":1000},27],["LinkReactUnsafeHrefConfig",[],{"log_unsafe_href":false},1182],["BanzaiConfig",[],{"EXPIRY":86400000,"MAX_SIZE":10000,"MAX_WAIT":150000,"RESTORE_WAIT":150000,"blacklist":["time_spent"],"gks":{"boosted_component":true,"boosted_pagelikes":true,"boosted_posts":true,"boosted_website":true,"jslogger":true,"mercury_send_error_logging":true,"pages_client_logging":true,"platform_oauth_client_events":true,"time_spent_bit_array":true,"useraction":true,"videos":true,"visibility_tracking":true,"vitals":true,"allow_userid_mismatch":true,"graphexplorer":true}},7],["CoreWarningGK",[],{"forceWarning":false},725],["FbtLogger",[],{"logger":null},288],["FbtQTOverrides",[],{"overrides":{"1_539bf175108659676097349f8b511a1d":"Donate to International Medical Corps now and Facebook will match your donation.","1_d1c1f6116da4d8f993a151fda3072cb5":"Donate to International Medical Corps today and join us in supporting relief efforts","1_6f7acce98bbf4cfdac77ebf5b9bad304":"100\u0025 of your donation will go to {=International Medical Corps} and their work in response to the Nepal earthquake. Facebook will also donate $2 million to local relief efforts.","1_8b130114c0a07a35b47bebd218149f60":"Support earthquake relief efforts","1_65c3391ebe4a1af8364ca4fbb8cb54d1":"Mobile Number or Email:","1_8d7e2c77c3375ec57db92d101f139964":"Donate to International Medical Corps now and support earthquake relief efforts."}},551],["FbtResultGK",[],{"shouldReturnFbtResult":false,"inlineMode":false},876],["IntlViewerContext",[],{"GENDER":50331648},772],["ReactGK",[],{"logTopLevelRenders":false,"useCreateElement":true},998],["AsyncRequestConfig",[],{"pkgCohort":"EXP1:DEFAULT","PKG_COHORT_KEY":"__pc","retryOnNetworkError":"1"},328],["ZeroCategoryHeader",[],{},1127],["BigPipeExperiments",[],{"preparse_content":"","prefetch":"none","download_js":"blocked_by_dom_ready","link_images_to_pagelets":false},907],["ErrorSignalConfig",[],{"uri":"https:\/\/error.facebook.com\/common\/scribe_endpoint.php"},319],["AccessibilityConfig",[],{"a11yDontMessWithTabindex":false,"a11yVirtualCursorTrigger":false,"a11yNewsfeedStoryEnumeration":false},1227],["SessionNameConfig",[],{"seed":"0HCA"},757],["PageTransitionsConfig",[],{"reloadOnBootloadError":false},1067],["LitestandShareAttachmentConfig",[],{"ALLOW_SIMPLE_CROP":true},1151],["PhotoSnowliftActionsGating",[],{"ALLOW_MAKE_COVER_PHOTO_BUTTON":false,"ALLOW_MAKE_PROFILE_PICTURE_BUTTON":false},887],["InitialServerTime",[],{"serverTime":1453673391000},204],["VideoPlayerAbortLoadingExperiment",[],{"canAbort":false,"withoutLoad":true},824]]);new (require("ServerJS"))().handle({"require":[["TimeSlice"],["markJSEnabled"],["lowerDomain"],["URLFragmentPrelude"],["Primer"],["BigPipe"],["Bootloader"]]});}, "ServerJ
         <script>requireLazy(["Bootloader"], function(Bootloader) {Bootloader.setResourceMap({"wgBwv":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yx\/r\/lcAFPjsaC54.js","crossOrigin":1},"uiSyu":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yW\/r\/lUGtGkkJtCW.js","crossOrigin":1},"ccpBO":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yn\/r\/8v2_hdH4Nfm.js","crossOrigin":1},"3Vrov":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yr\/r\/Xwv6OG7TyF2.js","crossOrigin":1},"QYX4S":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yN\/r\/ZNYeLfc3Lq4.js","crossOrigin":1},"+ClWy":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yF\/r\/A0qdgknEnD5.js","crossOrigin":1},"zf5gz":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yq\/r\/omMM3x4T6dD.js","crossOrigin":1},"HfyvS":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yg\/r\/suniArtcpji.js","crossOrigin":1},"UBQLK":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yd\/r\/z9_31cFlmgs.js","crossOrigin":1},"j+g5j":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yv\/r\/3g_-iVu6oiK.js","crossOrigin":1},"SnznU":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/ys\/r\/OBOPAdw3nyJ.js","crossOrigin":1},"L1k\/a":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yT\/r\/pLR_pv_fs_j.js","crossOrigin":1},"oE4Do":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/ye\/r\/K9O3qPDtfqb.js","crossOrigin":1},"ojTdz":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yN\/r\/_bYQL81FU1k.js","crossOrigin":1},"cNca2":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yS\/r\/_uW33I9lkJl.js","crossOrigin":1},"d7V4X":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yW\/r\/Q1WFQNCqpeo.js","crossOrigin":1},"nL8ID":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yW\/r\/Dppan5o6UJu.js","crossOrigin":1},"WSwTv":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y_\/r\/XXn49zk5GnD.js","crossOrigin":1},"xh2k3":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yV\/r\/ToVqvKf_5na.js","crossOrigin":1},"+sDYD":{"type":"css","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yz\/r\/QdsLq-CiiS7.css","permanent":1,"crossOrigin":1},"hC18Y":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yL\/r\/R7fdkQ_okPe.js","crossOrigin":1},"CdEld":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yB\/r\/wZTiu0lqrbU.js","crossOrigin":1},"a6Iiz":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yq\/r\/aKRUThMJLVG.js","crossOrigin":1},"Vsxjz":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yr\/r\/6Mogu8hdAuf.js","crossOrigin":1},"IFvRp":{"type":"css","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y0\/r\/xZTUaKp737F.css","crossOrigin":1},"TfQNt":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yD\/r\/p4TV91a7d5d.js","crossOrigin":1},"LGwqK":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y_\/r\/8veG8hmmZJm.js","crossOrigin":1},"GC9iL":{"type":"css","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yJ\/r\/Y2vIEhnV9XX.css","nonblocking":1,"crossOrigin":1},"5Krai":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y2\/r\/JT8shvtwWrm.js","crossOrigin":1},"i7F+L":{"type":"css","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yA\/r\/fpHVJ4kXijf.css","permanent":1,"crossOrigin":1},"2ouFz":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yK\/r\/-KPbrWnAx0Q.js","crossOrigin":1},"eVWAQ":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yf\/r\/nMp9wT0K0gJ.js","crossOrigin":1},"AtxWD":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yu\/r\/mOwquNMdiEH.js","crossOrigin":1},"Rs18G":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yY\/r\/z9xrgSKFbeZ.js","crossOrigin":1},"DOMtm":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yA\/r\/dOV
         requireLazy(["ix"], function(ix) {ix.add({"images\/platform\/registration\/about\/arrow_right.png":{"sprited":true,"spriteMapCssClass":"sp_k5i405GlExR","spriteCssClass":"sx_922c0c"},"images\/groups\/sell\/place_icon_sell.png":{"sprited":true,"spriteMapCssClass":"sp_k5i405GlExR","spriteCssClass":"sx_8f30d9"},"arrow-right:white:small":{"sprited":true,"spriteMapCssClass":"sp_WbN8fef7SYE","spriteCssClass":"sx_2db80b"}});});
      </script>
      <script>requireLazy(["InitialJSLoader"], function(InitialJSLoader) {InitialJSLoader.loadOnDOMContentReady(["eNbsO","wgBwv","V0yxN","uiSyu","2ouFz","hFs+y","3Vrov","xh2k3"]);});</script>
      <script>require("TimeSlice").guard(function() {require("ServerJSDefine").handleDefines([]);require("InitialJSLoader").handleServerJS({"elements":[["__elem_835c633a_0_0","login_form",1],["__elem_f46f4946_0_0","u_0_0",1],["__elem_f46f4946_0_1","u_0_1",1],["__elem_1edd4980_0_0","loginbutton",2],["__elem_072b8e64_0_0","u_0_3",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_1","u_0_4",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_2","u_0_5",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_3","u_0_6",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_4","u_0_7",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_5","u_0_8",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_6","u_0_9",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_7","u_0_a",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_8","u_0_b",1],["__elem_072b8e64_0_9","u_0_c",1],["__elem_a588f507_0_0","globalContainer",1],["__elem_85b7cbf7_0_0","login_form",1]],"require":[["PixelRatio","startDetecting",[],[1],[]],["ServiceWorkerLoginAndLogoutListener","listen",["__elem_1edd4980_0_0"],[{"__m":"__elem_1edd4980_0_0"},"login"],[]],["TimezoneAutoset","setInputValue",["__elem_f46f4946_0_0"],[{"__m":"__elem_f46f4946_0_0"},1453673391],[]],["ScreenDimensionsAutoSet","setInputValue",["__elem_f46f4946_0_1"],[{"__m":"__elem_f46f4946_0_1"}],[]],["LoginFormController","init",["__elem_835c633a_0_0","__elem_1edd4980_0_0"],[{"__m":"__elem_835c633a_0_0"},{"__m":"__elem_1edd4980_0_0"}],[]],["PostLoadJS","loadAndCall",[],["QuickSandSolver","solveAndUpdateForm",[1,"W??B\u0040?>`Y Y|\u0012g?i\nOU?pZ\u0004???U9??",10,42,100,"login_form","AZmVJ6wCoIXbQo0peRYrnEnrzTrYwEVCqC3JGiBezk46nys7gHyj1fBrjp07982h2ViMXj3e898IXF0VdpcdUJmVvJwCL-E3UH2FNa2FEJaTt-ljw95MJftAR7Tsxa4A0xCW5j4GN3ortHd1x6W0v6vdTrgpuRQ7lYxmPCYihf7gGpsFyMLeKG0G9snEvnn1Fz_6n-KSUjWl_7PtGFiiqa3WrLhOPdOicj-WkH8pjkUzWg"]],[]],["FocusListener"],["FlipDirectionOnKeypress"],["Cookie","setIfFirstPartyContext",[],["_js_datr","r0ulVvNlrvP3Y5eFbLGLbZzK",63072000000,"\/",false],[]],["Cookie","setIfFirstPartyContext",[],["_js_reg_fb_ref","https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/login.php?next=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.facebook.com\u00252Fgroups\u00252F123435454667253\u00252F",0,"\/",false],[]],["Cookie","setIfFirstPartyContext",[],["_js_reg_fb_gate","https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/login.php?next=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.facebook.com\u00252Fgroups\u00252F123435454667253\u00252F",0,"\/",false],[]],["Intl","setPhonologicalRules",[],[{"meta":{"\/_B\/":"([.,!?\\s]|^)","\/_E\/":"([.,!?\\s]|$)"},"patterns":{"\/\u0001(.*)('|&#039;)s\u0001(?:'|&#039;)s(.*)\/":"\u0001$1$2s\u0001$3","\/_\u0001([^\u0001]*)\u0001\/e":"mb_strtolower(\"\u0001$1\u0001\")","\/\\^\\x01([^\\x01])(?=[^\\x01]*\\x01)\/e":"mb_strtoupper(\"\u0001$1\")","\/_\u0001([^\u0001]*)\u0001\/":"javascript"}}],[]],["PostLoadJS","loadAndRequire",[],["DimensionTracking"],[]],["PostLoadJS","loadAndCall",[],["HighContrastMode","init",[{"isHCM":false,"spacerImage":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y4\/r\/-PAXP-deijE.gif"}]],[]],["PostLoadJS","loadAndCall",[],["DetectBrokenProxyCache","run",[0,"c_user"]],[]],["ClickRefLogger"],["ScriptPath","set",[],["\/login.php","ad976420",{"imp_id":"17a7d485"}],[]],["UserActionHistory"],["ScriptPathLogger","startLogging",[],[],[]],["TimeSpentBitArrayLogger","init",[],[],[]],["NavigationClickPointHandler"],["UITinyViewportAction","init",[],[],[]],["ResetScrollOnUnload","init",["__elem_a588f507_0_0"],[{"__m":"__elem_a588f507_0_0"}],[]],["PostLoadJS","loadAndCall",[],["WebStorageMonster","schedule",[]],[]],["AsyncRequestNectarLogging"],["LoggedOutSwitchingLocaleLogger","logOnClick",["__elem_072b8e64_0_0"],[{"__m":"__elem_072b8e64_0_0"},"en_US","en_US",0],[]],["LoggedOutSwitchingLocaleLogger","logOnClick",["__elem_072b8e64_0_1"],[{"__m":"__elem_072b8e64_0_1"},"en_US","es_LA",1],[]],["LoggedOutSwitchingLocaleLogger","logOnClick",["__elem_072b8e64_0_2"],[{"__m":"__elem_072b8e64_0_2"},"en_US","fr_FR",2],[]],["LoggedOutSwitchingLocaleLogger","logOnClick",["__elem_072b8e64_0_3"],[{"__m":"__elem_072b8e64_0_3"},"en_US","zh_CN",3],[]],["LoggedOutSwitchingLocaleLogger","logOnClick",["__elem_072b8e64_0_4"],[{"__m":"__elem_072b8e64_0_4"},"en_US","ar_AR",4],[]],["LoggedOutSwitchingLocaleLogger","logOnClick",["__elem_072b8e64_0_5"],[{"__m":"__el
         onloadRegister_DEPRECATED(function (){begin_polling_login_cookies("https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/groups\/123435454667253\/");});
      </script>
      <!-- BigPipe construction and first response -->
      <script>var bigPipe = new (require("BigPipe"))({"lid":"6243479675352150674","forceFinish":true});</script>
      <script>bigPipe.beforePageletArrive("first_response")</script>
      <script>require("TimeSlice").guard((function(){bigPipe.onPageletArrive({"id":"first_response","phase":0,"jsmods":{},"is_last":true,"allResources":["eNbsO","aT3o+","MQYLf","crKAN","Pv1hP","mwDzO","wgBwv","V0yxN","uiSyu","1Nw\/a","2ouFz","hFs+y","3Vrov","xh2k3"],"displayResources":["aT3o+","MQYLf","crKAN","Pv1hP","mwDzO","1Nw\/a"]});}),"onPageletArrive first_response",{"root":true,"pagelet":"first_response"})();</script><script>bigPipe.beforePageletArrive("last_response")</script>
      <script>require("TimeSlice").guard((function(){bigPipe.onPageletArrive({"id":"last_response","phase":1,"jsmods":{"define":[["TimeSpentConfig",[],{"0_delay":0,"0_timeout":8,"delay":200000,"timeout":64},142],["ImmediateActiveSecondsConfig",[],{"sampling_rate":0},423]]},"is_last":true,"allResources":["eNbsO","aT3o+","MQYLf","crKAN","Pv1hP","mwDzO","wgBwv","V0yxN","uiSyu","1Nw\/a","2ouFz","hFs+y","3Vrov","xh2k3"],"displayResources":["aT3o+","MQYLf","crKAN","Pv1hP","mwDzO","1Nw\/a"],"the_end":true});}),"onPageletArrive last_response",{"root":true,"pagelet":"last_response"})();</script>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What HTTP code are you getting back?

Comment: I have added the HTML output to the question

Comment: We don't necessarily want the response object (the html you posted), but the response status. Now, there's a good chance it's 20x since you got html back, but it would help, especially if it's in the 30x range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use the Facebook SDK to support logins in your app, I don't know if login just with an HTTP POST is available.

Here is the Getting started guide:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

And the Login example

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: I know that there is a Facebook sdk but I want to be able to use this to log into other websites as well...for example I want to be able to follow a similar process and log into a Gmail account and my school website as well

Comment: You are not going to be able to do that. Most of the websites implement a kind of difficult way to log in (OAuth), for example, to log in with Twitter, you need to first set up an app in [this page][apps.twitter.com], then create client credentials, then do the login. It is called OAuth. Make sure you check this Wikipedia link containing why did they do it and some controversy about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth